# Create third dataframe based on condition applied to two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(rng.rand(1000, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(rng.rand(1000, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

I also have a column consisting of "Y" and "N":

```
df0['Split'] = ['Y', 'N', 'Y'...]
```

I want to create a 3rd dataframe that returns df1 if df0['Split'] = 'Y' and returns df2 if df0['Split'] = 'N'. I'd like to keep the shape of the original two dataframes if possible.

I thought I could do something such as the following:

```
if df0['Split'] == Y:
    return df1
if df0['Split'] == N:
    return df2
else:
    return 0
```

In reality, I have a lot more columns than A through C. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Boolean filtering to construct two dataframes, combine via `pd.concat`, then `sort_index`. The solution assumes all 3 dataframes share the same index.

```
mask = df0['Split'] == 'Y'
res = pd.concat([df1[mask], df2[~mask]]).sort_index()
```